# How to check total occurrence of a character in string

Tags: php, string

I want to find out total occurrence of particular character in string.
 my code is:

```
  $str = 'aabbbcccccaa';

  for ($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++){
    $len = 0;
    for ($j=$i;$j<=strlen($str);$j++){
        if($str[$i] == $str[$j]){
        $len++;
        }
    }
    echo "\n".$str[$i].' len is '.$len;
}
```

my output is  like:

```
  a len is 4
  a len is 3
  b len is 3
  b len is 2
  b len is 1
  c len is 5
  c len is 4
  c len is 3
  c len is 2
  c len is 1
  a len is 2
  a len is 1
```

but I want something like:

```
  a len is 4
  b len is 3
  c len is 5 only
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: echo strlen($str); echo substr_count($str, 'a');

Comment: <?php
$data = "aabbbcccccaa";
foreach (count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val) {
   echo chr($i)."  len is $val<br/>";
}
?>

Comment: @pankaj what is difference between yours and Manish and Hanky ans ????

Comment: both provide answer same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)**

```
<?php
$data = "Two Ts and one F.";

foreach (count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val) {
   echo "There were $val instance(s) of \"" , chr($i) , "\" in the string.\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: same question possible for global ?? here we use foreach so it work only for php and i want code which work in all language . is it possible ????

Comment: Nope, nothing works in *every* language, every language has its own way of doing things. There can't be one solution for all. Only the algo will remain same.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `substr_count()`. It's right here in the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

or perhaps `count_chars()` would be even better for a generic solution:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php

Always check the manuals before creating something yourself.. there just might be a function there that does exactly what you want..

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'aabbbcccccaa';

foreach (count_chars($str, 1) as $i => $val) {
   echo  chr($i), " len is $val " , "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Simply Implement the bellow way !

Our Custom Function :

```
function count_chars_unicode($str, $x = false) {
    $tmp = preg_split('//u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    foreach ($tmp as $c) {
        $chr[$c] = isset($chr[$c]) ? $chr[$c] + 1 : 1;
    }
    return is_bool($x)
        ? ($x ? $chr : count($chr))
        : $chr[$x];
}
```

Usage :

```
print_r(count_chars_unicode('aabbbcccccaa', true));
```

O/P

Array ( [a] => 4 [b] => 3 [c] => 5 )

```
print_r(count_chars_unicode('aabbbcccccaa', 'a'));  // frequency of "a"
```

O/P : 4

```
print_r(count_chars_unicode('aabbbcccccaa'));  // count of uniq chars
```

O/P : 3